# How to update knockout model in mvc3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I've been playing with MVC3 with KnockoutJs for a few weeks and I've been wondering about something

say I have an mvc action which returns a simple list

```
public ActionResult AddFoos()
{
    List<Foo> funds = new List<Foo>();     
    .. etc
    return Json(funds.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

which is then passed into the view model

```
var viewModel = {
  fooChocies: ko.mapping.fromJS([]),
  fooOptions: ko.mapping.fromJS([]),
    loadInitialData: function () {

        ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData, dataMappingOptions, viewModel.fooOptions);
    },
};
```

In my type Foo I also have properties that show or hide ui elements

```
var Foo = function (data, preselect) {


    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.number = ko.observable('');


    self.showProducts = ko.observable(false);   <---
    self.displayBigPanel = ko.observable(false);  <---

   }
```

My approach so far as been to dynamically create elements of the form

which passes through the ModelBinder and creates a List< Foo > as a parameter for controller action.

Finally the **question**...

When the user navigates back to this page I need to restore the UI with the fooChoices the user made.

It seems I have 2 choices with rebuilding the user selections (both via extension methods)

1. Use raw json as seen by

   ```
   ko.toJSON(viewModel.fooChoices))
   ```

which in addition to basic model properties also provides info on hiding and displaying UI elements,

```
            sb.Append("viewModel.fooCghoices= ko.mapping.fromJS(" + json + ");");
            sb.Append("ko.applyBindings(viewModel);");
            return new HtmlString(sb.ToString());
```

thus sending client ui info to the server and back

or

1. Manipulate the ViewModel directly in effect simulating the user actions

   ```
           sb.Append("viewModel.fooChoices.push(new Foo(1509));");
           sb.Append("viewModel.fooChoices()[0].selectedSubFoo = new Foo(273);");
           sb.Append("viewModel.fooChoices()[0].showProducts(true);");
   ```

In either case it feels a bit off and that a better pattern is out there. Would like to know if one way is better than the other or none of the above.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently, your controller method returns a list of `Foo`.  Consider creating a more complex object that holds both your Foos and your choices.

```
public class FooViewModel 
{
  public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; };
  public UserChoices { get; set; }
}
```

Change your controller method so that it returns `FooViewModel`.  This means user choices will be returned along with any Foos you are interested in.

```
public ActionResult AddFoos()
{
    // Are there any choices stored in session?
    // Use those first, otherwise create a new UserChoices object
    UserChoices choices = 
        Session["User.Choices"] as UserChoices ?? new UserChoices();


    List<Foo> funds = new List<Foo>();     
    .. etc

    FooViewModel vm = new FooViewModel() { Foos = funds; UserChoices = choices };

    // Return the whole object, containing Choices and Foos
    return Json(vm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also, consider some kind of action filter to allow you to pass complete objects easily.  ObjectFilter is a good approach.  It allows you to pass complex object structures easily without having to rely on specific markup.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/863/passing-json-into-an-asp-net-mvc-controller.aspx

ObjectFilter above a controller method.  Pretty simple, just declaring that the controller should attempt to treat any incoming parameter called `fooStuff` as type `FooViewModel`.

```
    [HttpPost, 
     ObjectFilter(Param = "fooStuff", RootType = typeof(FooViewModel)), 
     UnitOfWork]
    public JsonResult ProcessFoos(FooViewModel fooStuff) {
```

By defining a corresponding JavaScript view model, you can just convert the whole thing to a json string and pass it to the controller method fully populated.

So, example of corresponding js vm would be:-

```
var fooViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.Foos = ko.observableArray(data.Foos);
  self.UserChoices = ko.observable(data.UserChoices);


  // Don't worry about properties or methods that don't exist
  // on the C# end of things.  They'll just be ignored.
  self.usefulJSOnlyMethod = function() {
    // behaviour
  };
}

var userChoice = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.DinnerId = ko.observable(data.DinnerId);
}
```

Typical call to a controller method decorated by `ObjectFilter` would be something like this ( assuming self is a `fooViewModel` ):-

```
var queryData = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);
$.ajax(
   //...
   data: queryData,
```

Any matching ( same name, same type case-sensitive ) property from the js vm will automatically end up in the `fooStuff` parameter of your controller method.  Time to save those choices:-

Also note that I'm persisting user choices in the session here.  This'll allow them to be picked up by any other controller method which may need them ( example in AddFoos above ).

```
    [HttpPost, 
     ObjectFilter(Param = "fooStuff", RootType = typeof(FooViewModel)), 
     UnitOfWork]
    public JsonResult ProcessFoos(FooViewModel fooStuff) 
    {
        // hey!  I have a fully mapped FooViewModel right here!
        // ( _fooServices.ProcessFoos will return updated version of viewmodel )
        FooViewModel vm = _fooServices.ProcessFoos(fooStuff);

        // What about those choices?
        // Put them in the session at this point in case anyone else comes asking
        // after them.
        Session["User.Choices"] = vm.UserChoices;

        return Json(vm);
    }
```

Because we've:-

- Defined a better C# view model
- Defined a corresponding JS view model
- Including UserChoices as part of that view model

....restoring the choice is simple at this point.  Reference the part of the view model that contains the user's selected choice.

```
<select id="dinnerChoice"
   data-bind="value: UserChoices.DinnerId"
>
</select>
```

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen. Thanks a lot Paul!